# Adding quoted value to Enum

Tags: java, string, enums, special-characters

I created Enum with additional quoted in string value. When i call this value from Enum in any class i got value, but without quotes.

My Enum:

```
public enum ValueMapping {
 BSE_M("BSE_MEDIUM"),
 REPS("\"REPS\""),
 TBOMD("TBOMD");

 private String name;

 ValueMapping(String name) {
     this.name = name;
 }

 public String getName() {
     return name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
     this.name = name;
 }

 public static ValueMapping getByName(String name) {
     ValueMapping result = null;
     for (ValueMapping operName : values()) {
         if (operName.getName().equals(name)) {
             result = operName;
             break;
         }
     }
     return result;
 }
}
```

How i try to get value from Enum:

```
ValueMapping.REPS.name()
```

**Question: Is any way to get value from Enum with quotation marks?**

Comment: But you created a method `getName()` but called `.name()`. Isn't `.name()` just going to return the default `.toString()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `getName()` as:

```
ValueMapping.REPS.getName()
```

for e.g.

```
System.out.println(ValueMapping.REPS.getName());
```

would print ***"REPS"***

Answer (score 3):

There is no mechanism to override `name()` because the method is `final`. And you can't add quotation marks to the name of an enum variable.

So, the only way to get `"REPS"` is to call `ValueMapping.REPS.getName()`.